# Некорректная сборка

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, less

Использую Webpack чтобы файли из папки frontend - транспилировать ES6 в ES5 и скомпилировать Less в CSS и собрать это всё в папку public. Конфиг написал руководствуясь официальной документацией. Но проблема в том, что JS транспилится и переносится в нужную директорию, а компиляция и сборка Less игнорируется.
Вот мой конфиг:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const PATHS = {
    app: path.join(__dirname, 'frontend'),
    build: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
};

module.exports = {
    entry: PATHS.app,
    output: {
        path: PATHS.build,
        filename: 'index.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['babel-preset-env']
              }
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              fallback: 'style-loader',
              use: [
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        url: false,
                        minimize: true,
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    loader: 'less-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }
              ]
            })
          }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css")
    ]
};
```

Тут скрины структуры проекта до сборки и после:

[image: До]

[image: После]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил сам, осмотрев весь проект. Может кому поможет - я конфиг написал правильно, только в index.js не поставил импорт.

```
import '../frontend/index.less';
```